# javax/validation/validation error with javax/javaee-api-6.0

Tags: hibernate, session, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to configure my session factory, 
according to google's results putting javaee-api in provided scope should solve the problem, but it does not :/

full pom.xml
[code]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.me.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>PersonnesServices</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>PersonnesServices</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <!-- Junit -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- HIBERNATE -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2</version>
   </dependency>

   <!--  HSQLDB -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.8</version>
   </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

[/code]

my hibernate.cfg.xml

[code]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>
         <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping class="com.me.dto.Personne"/>
        <mapping class="com.me.dto.Ecole"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

[/code]

and my error :

[code]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1741)
    at com.csc.util.HibernateUtil.configureSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at com.csc.services.test.main(test.java:20)
```

[/code]

Any of you already have encountered such problems?
thanks.

Comment: additionals information :putting a "test" scope makes the program works but the built (mvn clean install) is failing.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using javaee-web-api 6 and hibernate when I run the junit tests.

I fixed it replacing:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

for:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never: You could use jboss-javaee-6.0 instead of javaee-api-6.0.

Have a look here [Maven: hibernate-entitymanager together with javaee-api break my unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638479/maven-hibernate-entitymanager-together-with-javaee-api-break-my-unit-tests)

Comment: I totaly forgot to awnser this, the problem was that I was using the version 6 with a Jboss 5.1 wich are both incompatible, using javaee-api-5 solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue while running JUnits and got solved by following below steps: 
1. Adding below dependencies above hibernate dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

2. I screwed my build path, so removed ".classpath" file (eclipse>navigator) and did maven>update project to reset my build path

Then it worked