# How to test DAOs using hibernate in JUnit4

Tags: java, hibernate, junit4

This seems to be a similar question ([Test DAO in java using Junit4 and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916014/test-dao-in-java-using-junit4-and-hibernate)), but he's getting the session created successfully. I'm unable to create the session.

Please note that I'm not using Spring. I just need to test my DAOs which create sessions using HibernateUtil.java

My Sample Test Code (in test packages)

```
public void testGetBean() {
    System.out.println("getBean");
    int idaccount = 0;
    Account expResult = null;
    Account result = DAOAccount.getBean(idaccount);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
    // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    //fail("The test case is a prototype.");
}
```

And here is DAOAccount getBean() (in source packages)

```
public static Account getBean(int idaccount) {
    Account ac = null;
    Session sess = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
    Query q = sess.createQuery("from Account where idaccount=:id");
    q.setInteger("id", idaccount);
    ac = (Account) q.uniqueResult();
    tx.commit();
    sess.close();
    return ac;
}
```

NewHibernateUtil.java (in source packages)

```
public class NewHibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
        // config file.
//            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

and here is the stack trace [image]

Below is the project structure :

[image]

Actual Exception Stacktrace as asked by @Subin

```
[2012-12-29 16:36:24.347] [ INFO] Configuration.applyHibernateValidatorLegacyConstraintsOnDDL:1646 - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/validation/Validation
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationActivator.applyDDL(BeanValidationActivator.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyBeanValidationConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1674)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1624)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1415)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1826)
    at dao.NewHibernateUtil.<clinit>(NewHibernateUtil.java:25)
    at dao.DAOAccount.getAccounts(DAOAccount.java:77)
    at dao.DAOAccountTest.testGetAccounts_User(DAOAccountTest.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:338)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:997)
```

Comment: post the exception trace

Comment: @Subin I've edited the question and added the exception trace.

Comment: please see my answer , is hibernate.cfg.xml in classpath.?

Comment: log the actual exception using ex.printStackTrace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> public Configuration configure()
>                           throws HibernateException
>   Use the mappings and properties specified in an application resource named hibernate.cfg.xml.
>   Throws: HibernateException

`Configuration.configure()` will work correctly only if `hibernate.cfg.xml` is available as application resource. or classpath.

If you are using eclipse to invoke your Junit test, add hibernate.cfg.xml to classpath, since you are using maven do you have it in src/main/resources

Please see this link to see, why java.lang.ClassFormatError: happens.
[Maven: hibernate-entitymanager together with javaee-api break my unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638479/maven-hibernate-entitymanager-together-with-javaee-api-break-my-unit-tests)

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 6.9 to invoke the test and yes I'm having configuration xml in src/main/resources.

Comment: is it named hibernate.cfg.xml ?

Comment: Yes, it's named hibernate.cfg.xml. 
Also it's working perfect on normal running the project. Only testing is not working.
I've edited the question to show the project structure.

Comment: can you log the actual exception `catch (Exception ex) {
        // ex.printStackTrace() 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }` using print stack trace as shown.

Comment: I've added the complete stack-trace.

Comment: I still see only ExceptionInitializationError.

Comment: Sorry, I was formatting the exception trace which took time. You might be able to see it now.

Comment: yes, I have updated answer with a SO link, check that and see if your case is similar.

Comment: yes, I'm having the same issue. So here's the temporary solution, for testing I removed the javaee dependency.

Comment: Hi, I'm also facing the same problem, & When I removed the javaee dependency it worked well. But could you please let us know what is the permanent solution if you know?